# My ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, access-denied

When I try to connect the MySQL Server by command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get error "Access denied". I'm sure that the password is right.

When I use the

```
mysqld --defaults-files "xxx\my.ini" --console --skip-grant-tables
```

option, I can access in, but when I quit this, access is denied again.

How could I sovle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the root password.

For MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

This can be dangerous, read the full official instructions before: [How to Reset the Root Password?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: I have already known the password, but the access is still denied.

Comment: Try to reset the password with the password you already know.

Comment: I have `mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)` and I tried using `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';` but I get `ALTER: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

[Try Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html)

1. Restart mysql with the --skip-grant-tables option
2. In the mysql client : `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
3. `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`

Comment: I did that, but it sitll denied. Just only in the skip-grant tables option, I can connect the server.